# For each row, replace values from specific columns (defined by another dataframe), with a value from a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Let's say we have:

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10) , v2=rnorm(10), v3=rnorm(10), v4=rnorm(10))
```

as well as

```
df2 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10) , v2=rnorm(10), v3=rnorm(10), v4=rnorm(10))
vector <- c(17,21,33,41,50,63,72,81,91,10)
```

df1 and df2 have same column names and df2 is generated by processing of df1.

For each row in df2, I would like to replace a value that meets the condition `< 0.5` in df1, with the corresponding value of the vector.

For example, if any of the columns of the first row in df1 has a value lower than 0.5, then the corresponding column(s) of the first row in df2 will have to be replaced with the first element of the vector, that is 17. For the second row, they will be replaced with 21 etc.

I picture some `apply` and a custom made function would do the trick but I am not able to figure it out. Thank you in advance for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)**

My approach was:

```
idx <- df1 < .5
tmp <- idx * vector
df2[idx] <- tmp[idx]
```

**2)**

A second option provided by [@MartinGal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12505251/martin-gal) in the comments:

```
df2 * (df1>=0.5) + (df1<0.5) * vector
```

Result is

```
df2
#           v1            v2          v3         v4
#1  -1.4936251  5.676206e-01 -0.08610730 17.0000000
#2  21.0000000  2.100000e+01 -0.88767902 21.0000000
#3  33.0000000  6.288407e-05 33.00000000 33.0000000
#4  41.0000000  1.122890e+00 -0.02944488 41.0000000
#5  50.0000000  5.000000e+01 50.00000000 50.0000000
#6  -0.4282589  6.300000e+01 63.00000000 63.0000000
#7  72.0000000  7.200000e+01 72.00000000 72.0000000
#8  81.0000000  8.100000e+01 81.00000000 -0.8002822
#9  -1.2247480  9.100000e+01 91.00000000 91.0000000
#10  0.1795164 -5.246948e-02 10.00000000 10.0000000
```

---

We first check at which positions `df1` is `< .5` and multiply this by `vector` to get this matrix

```
idx <- df1 < .5
tmp <- (idx) * vector
tmp
#      v1 v2 v3 v4
# [1,]  0  0  0 17
# [2,] 21 21  0 21
# [3,] 33  0 33 33
# [4,] 41  0  0 41
# [5,] 50 50 50 50
# [6,]  0 63 63 63
# [7,] 72 72 72 72
# [8,] 81 81 81  0
# [9,]  0 91 91 91
#[10,]  0  0 10 10
```

These are the values you want to insert in `df2` at the position where `idx` equals `TRUE`.

So the next step is to replace the those values in `df2` using a logical matrix, i.e. `idx`:

```
df2[idx] <- tmp[idx]
```

Comment: Brilliant idea! If I'm not mistaken this can be "simplified" to `df2 * (df1>=0.5) + (df1<0.5) * vector`

Comment: @MartinGal I think your approach is excellent. Please post as answer.

Comment: I just used your approach so it's basically just a variation of your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `Map` from `base R`

```
data.frame(Map(function(x, y) ifelse(x < 0.5, vector, y) , df1, df2))
```

---

Or using `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(df1, df2, ~ case_when(.x < 0.5 ~  vector, TRUE~ .y))
```